# random.sample and "selection order"

Tags: python, random

```
help(random.sample)
```

says "The resulting list is in **selection order** so that all sub-slices will also be valid random samples"

What does **selection order** mean? If there were no requirement for **selection order**, how would resulting list look like? How could sub-slice not be a valid random sample?

**Upd** As far as I understood, it means that results will not be sorted in any way probably.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`random.sample(population, k)`

Given a `population` sequence it returns a list of length `k` with elements chosen (or **selected**) from `population`. **Selection Order** refers to *order* in which each of the elements are selected (random). The list is thus not sorted by indexes in population but by how the selection was made. Thus any-subslice of returned list is also a random sample for the population.

Example -

```
>>> import random
>>> population=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,]
>>> ls=random.sample(population,5)
>>> ls
[1, 11, 7, 12, 6]
```

The returned list has elements *in the order they were selected*. So you can use sub-slicing on `ls` and not lose randomness

```
>>> ls[:3]
[1, 11, 7]
```

If selection ordering was not enforced, you could have `ls` look like

```
[1,6,7,11,12]
```

The sub-slice would then not be completely random but constrained by the length of slice. E.g. The greatest value cannot occur in a sub-slice of length 3 (In this case that would be `[1, 6, 7]`)

Comment: Does "in selection order" mean "not sorted"?

Comment: `range(1, 13)` looks better btw

Comment: @user1307996 yup "in selection order" means "in the order they were selected" - So you could pick a 12, then a 5, then a 1 and so on to make your list. You are picking them randomly and appending to return list

Answer (score 2):

The full help string is:

> sample(self, population, k) method of random.Random instance
>   Chooses k unique random elements from a population sequence.
>
> Returns a new list containing elements from the population while
>   leaving the original population unchanged. The resulting list is
>   in selection order so that all sub-slices will also be valid random
>   samples. This allows raffle winners (the sample) to be partitioned
>   into grand prize and second place winners (the subslices).
>
> Members of the population need not be hashable or unique. If the
>   population contains repeats, then each occurrence is a possible
>   selection in the sample.
>
> To choose a sample in a range of integers, use xrange as an argument.
>   This is especially fast and space efficient for sampling from a
>   large population: sample(xrange(10000000), 60)

So taking the example of a raffle; all the tickets rolling around inside the drum are the `population`, and `k` is the number of tickets drawn. The set of all the tickets drawn is the result of the random `sample`.

The `sample` is not sorted, nor altered in any way, it is in the order it is drawn. If you imagine that you went to a raffle, and they drew 100 tickets first, and discarded them, and then started drawing the actual tickets, the set of winning tickets would still be a random `sample` of the `population`. This is equivalent to taking slices of the first larger `sample`.

What it's saying, is that any sub slice of any sample, is still a valid random sample.

To answer your questions;

**selection order** is just the order in which the values are drawn to make up the sample.

**without ensuring selection order** the sample may be sorted somehow.

The following code you can imagine creating a random sample ensuring selection order:

```
def sample(population, k):
    sample = []
    popsize = len(population)-1
    while len(sample) <= k:
        r = population[random.randint(0, popsize]
        if r not in sample:
            sample.append(r)

    return sample
```

Comment: "without ensuring selection order the sample may be sorted somehow." random.sample can return sorted seq, you cant force it. `random.sample([1], 1)`

Comment: As in, if you don't require the sample to have selection order, then there's nothing to stop you sorting it.